# Using ftp_get() when there are "spaces" in the file path and filename

Tags: php, csv, ftp, filesystems

I need to download a file via PHP [`ftp_get()`](http://php.net/ftp_get), but the foolish provider is using directories and file names contaning whitespace.. The file path I'm dealing with is similar to `/product info/more stuff/inventory and stuff.csv`

The spaces in the path and in the filename itself is making it difficult to retrieve anything. I already tried the following without success:

1. `$path = "/product\ info/more\ stuff/inventory\ and\ stuff.csv";`
2. `$path = "/product%20info/more%20stuff/inventory%20and%20stuff.csv";`
3. `$path = '"/product info/more stuff/inventory and stuff.csv"';`

Thanks again for taking the time to help me out.

Comment: Thanks for the edit Mario.. I feel like i looked everywhere and tried them all, but still have not found a solution :( . Even a point in the right direction is much appreciated. Thanks again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image: FTP?]

Your third attempt, *quoting the complete path*, was already the recommended approach. Though it very much depends on the actual server implementation.

[FTP per RFC859](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc959.txt) is comprised of a terminal session and a data transfer channel. Basically the FTP server provides a mini-shell on the command port. As such, typical shell string escaping rules do apply. URL encoding can be ruled out here.

I'd advise first to use single quotes however. Preferrably use [`escapeshellarg()`](http://php.net/escapeshellarg) to apply them. And try [`ftp_nb_get()`](http://php.net/ftp_nb_get) while at it.

```
$path = "/foo foo/bar bar/baz baz.csv";
ftp_nb_get($con, "save.csv", escapeshellarg($path), 2);
```

If that doesn't work, further debugging is necessary. While all ftp_* function arguments [are left unprocessed](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/ftp/ftp.c), you could as well try to send a [`ftp_raw`](http://php.net/ftp_raw) request. This won't actually activate the data channel reading, but might return a more concrete error response.

```
print_r(ftp_raw($con, "RETR '/path to/some file.csv'\r\n"));
```

And I'm just gonna say it, if you're still getting a file not found error then; it's entirely possible that the file really doesn't exist at the presumed location. In that case manually traverse the directory structure with [`ftp_nlist`](http://php.net/ftp_nlist) and [`ftp_rawlist`](http://php.net/ftp_rawlist) with `var_dump` (in case of extra trailing spaces for subdirs).

Alternatively just use [PHPs ftp:// stream wrapper](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.ftp.php) (which also supports PASV mode). Whose implementation is distinct from that of the ext/ftp functions. Here funnily enough, URL encoding is again the correct approach, but quoting still necessary ([ftp_fopen_wrapper.c](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/standard/ftp_fopen_wrapper.c) does not quote itself):

```
= file_get_contents("ftp://user:pw@example.org/'path%20to/file%20and.csv'");
// Inline quotes may likely trip up some FTP server implementations..
```

A much better alternative though is just using [`cURL`](http://php.net/cURL).

```
// You'll have to use the long-winded PHP curl functions of course.
print curl("ftp://.../file with spaces.csv")->exec();
```

Last option is just resorting to calling a Unixland client. (If not wget, than a plain ftp client.)

```
$url = escapeshellarg("ftp://user:pw@ftp.example.org/$path");
$file = `wget $url`;
```

If you still can't retrieve any files, you'll have to look for an alternative FTP client in PHP for further debugging. Guess [who wrote one](http://fossil.include-once.org/upgradephp/artifact/900314894ee45d3b160a21641b702b982f246d8c).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this post is rich with alternatives! I was able to grab the file via cURL. I'd +2 this if i could :)

Answer (score 1):

To get a list of files or folders with spaces in the path.

```
ftp_chdir($conn, $path);

$children = ftp_rawlist($conn,'-a .');
```

[Source](http://guruquest.net/question/php-ftp_rawlist-not-getting-directory-list-with-white-space-in-name/)